# selenium - chrome/webdriver not picking up profile and Applicable driver not found; attempting to install with Selenium

Tags: javascript, macos, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've downloaded both the chrome-webdriver and the 'chrome app for testing' matching versions and placed them near my code.

structure:

```
/src/index.ts
/drivers/chrome // <- Since this is on a MacOS I am providing the full path to the binary
/drivers/chrome-webdriver
```

Here's my selenium driver declaration :

```
 let chromeOptions = new chrome.Options();

    chromeOptions.addArguments('user-data-dir=' + chromeUserDataPath);
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--profile-directory=Default") // <- I've tried without this too
    chromeOptions.addArguments('executable-path=' + driverPath);
    chromeOptions.setChromeBinaryPath(chromePath);

    let driver: WebDriver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(chromeOptions).build();
```

Error that pops up :

`Applicable driver not found; attempting to install with Selenium Manager (Beta)`

*FYI* I don't have the manager setup. My goal is to point to the webdriver, chrome-binary, and user data.

A few things I've tried

1. Changed the chromeUserDataPath completely to a copied directory (same issue)
2. I do check in Chrome version output and it does show the right path to the user data directory/profile.

**NOTES** I code on a Windows PC and Mac the only one giving me issues is Mac. Generally speaking things don't need to change except normalizing the PATH and providing the proper path right? Any help/tips would be appreciated didn't think MacOS would cause such a headache :/

I know loading the default profile is bad practice but this is for a personal project and I don't care about it in this case.

**What I see**

1. Chrome for Testing (the pointed binary) does open up and should be. ✅
2. The user data path is correctly pointed at, I checked this by both deleting it making sure it's the one and only profile chrome is making. Also, the version page on chrome changes when a proper profile is loaded.
3. No user data is loaded, cookies, website data/history etc... On Windows with the same setup everything loads fine.